# Striping the text from the nested list and save the content into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a nested list like below,

```
[
    [
        '<p><strong>Mike</strong><br>Cardiologist</br></p>',
        '<p><strong>Alexandra</strong><br> Cardiac Surgeon</br></p>'
    ],

    [
        '<p><strong>Henna</strong><br/>physician</p>',
        '<p><strong>Gregg</strong><br/> Echocardiographer</p>'
    ]
]
```

I can either strip the text from it or I can write in the csv with all those tags. I don't know how to achieve both.

I want the data to be printed in CSV file as shown below,

```
Mike:Cardiologist, Alexandra:Cardiac Surgeon # This is first list in the parent list

Henna:physician, Gregg:Echocardiographer          # This is second list in the parent list
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an example for you.

**Code:**

```
import re
import csv

input_list = [
    [
        "<p><strong>Mike</strong><br>Cardiologist</br></p>",
        "<p><strong>Alexandra</strong><br> Cardiac Surgeon</br></p>",
    ],
    [
        "<p><strong>Henna</strong><br/>physician</p>",
        "<p><strong>Gregg</strong><br/> Echocardiographer</p>",
    ],
]

with open("test.csv", mode="w") as opened_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(opened_csv, delimiter=",")
    for group in input_list:
        tmp_list = []
        for elem in group:
            result = re.sub("<[^>]*>", " ", elem)
            result = " ".join(result.split())
            tmp_list.append(result.strip().replace(" ", ":", 1))
        csv_writer.writerow(tmp_list)
```

**test.csv file:**

```
Mike:Cardiologist,Alexandra:Cardiac Surgeon
Henna:physician,Gregg:Echocardiographer
```